# If statement, vlookup, etc between two tabs in one workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook for tasks assigned and a 'summary' sheet for our project manager.

What I would like to do is on the summary sheet, in column H, return the count of 'Pending' items from the task list sheet. So my project manager can see, at a glance, how many items are pending per client.

Summary Sheet

[image]

Task List

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I know there should be a vlookup in here somewhere based on client name but I am bit rusty with excel formulas.

Comment: [`COUNTIFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is the formula you want.

Comment: Do you have a key/unique identifier for the client? I'm not seeing any similarities in Client Name/Company Name and Client in Task List (might be that they're just not visible in the list).

Comment: I would be using Company Name and Client as the unique identifiers.

Comment: Then use those as the criteria in the `COUNTIFS()` formula, if you have an issue with getting it to work, let us know :)

Comment: Yes please help! I have been doing research and I'm just getting more lost and confused on how to make this work between multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula used:

```
=COUNTIFS('Task List'!C2:C15,'Summary Sheet'!A2,'Task List'!E2:E16,"Pending")
```

Or if you want it in one go:

```
=BYROW(A2:A6,LAMBDA(x, COUNTIFS('Task List'!C2:C15,x,'Task List'!E2:E15',"Pending")))
```

Summary Sheet (name of actual sheet):
[image]
Task List (name of sheet):
[image]